# SonarCube "Refactoring Nested Code Blocks in C# for Improved Readability"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, sonarqube, query-optimization

Wahat is wrong with this class? How can fix it?

```
public async Task<CommandResponse> HandleAsync(CrudValidationRequest command)
        {
            int result = 0;
            int UserId = _principalProvider.User.HarmonyId;
            string ValidationDataJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(command);
            {
```

**Extract this nested code block into a separate method.**

```
            result = await _suitDbCon.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<int>(SqlCommands.CRUDValidationCommand, new
            {
                ValidationDataJSON,
                UserId
            });
        }
        var response = new CommandResponse(result);
        return response;
    }
    public async Task<CommandResponse> HandleAsync(DeleteValidationRequest command)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int UserId = _principalProvider.User.HarmonyId;
        {
```

****Extract this nested code block into a separate method.****

```
        result = await _suitDbCon.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<int>(SqlCommands.DeleteValidationCommand, new
        {
            command.ValidationId,
            UserId
        });
    }
    var response = new CommandResponse(result);
    return response;
```